# align two table in single row

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have four table and  want to display two table in single row.I have used jspdf and autotable plugn.
I can able to show tables separately.I want to display it in single row.First two rows display properly.I struch with 4th table.
my fiddle [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/dLfszq0k/1/)

```js
function generate(enhance) {
  //const doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm');
 const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
 
  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById('geo_summarynew'));
 doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);
  var res3 = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById('group2new'));
  doc.save('test Report');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<button id="cmd" class="pdf-download" onclick="generate(true)">Make PDF</button>
<table id="geo_summarynew">
   <thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">
      <tr>
         <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Header1</th>
         <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Header1</th>
         <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Header3</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>test1</td>
         <td>34</td>
         <td>8471320</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>test4</td>
         <td>24</td>
         <td>589</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>test3</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table id="group2new">
   <thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">
      <tr>
         <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Header4</th>
         <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Header5</th>
         <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Header6</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>test4</td>
         <td>34</td>
         <td>8471320</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>test5</td>
         <td>24</td>
         <td>589</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>test6</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<button id="cmd" class="pdf-download" onclick="generate(true)">Make PDF</button>


<div class="pdfcontainer">
<div style="display: inline-block;">
<table id="geo_summarynew" style='position:relative;float:left;width:50%;'>
<thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff"><tr><th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Opportunity</th><th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Count</th><th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Value</th></tr></thead> <tbody><tr><td>Qualified</td><td>34</td><td>8471320</td></tr><tr><td>Negotiation &amp; Contracting</td><td>24</td><td>5716289</td></tr><tr><td>Proposal Submitted</td><td>61</td><td>25818992</td></tr></tbody></table>


<table id="group2new" style='position:relative;float:right;width:50%;'> <thead> <tr><th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Opportunity</th><th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000" data-style="Header">Pipeline Count</th><th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Pipeline Value</th></tr></thead> <tbody><tr><td>Closed Won</td><td>11</td><td>5071835</td></tr></tbody></table>

</div>

<div style="display: inline-block;">

<table style='position:relative;float:left;width:50%;' id="group3new"> <thead> <tr><th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000" data-style="Header">Opportunity</th><th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000" data-style="Header">Pipeline Count</th></tr></thead> <tbody><tr><td>Closed Lost</td><td>78</td></tr><tr><td>Deferred Opportunity</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table>


<table style='position:relative;float:right;width:50%;' id="group4new"> <thead> <tr><th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000" data-style="Header">Opportunity</th><th style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000" data-style="Header">Pipeline Count</th></tr></thead> <tbody><tr><td>Identified</td><td>261</td></tr><tr><td>QO under Evaluation</td><td>20</td></tr></tbody></table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use flex for this kind of placement

```js
function generate(enhance) {
  //const doc = new jsPDF('l', 'mm');
 const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4');
 
  var res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById('geo_summarynew'));
 doc.autoTable(res.columns, res.data);
  var res3 = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(document.getElementById('group2new'));
  doc.save('test Report');
}
```

```css
#container{
display:flex;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://simonbengtsson.github.io/jsPDF-AutoTable/dist/jspdf.plugin.autotable.js"></script>
<button id="cmd" class="pdf-download" onclick="generate(true)">Make PDF</button>
<div id='container'>
<table id="geo_summarynew">
   <thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">
      <tr>
         <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Header1</th>
         <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Header1</th>
         <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Header3</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>test1</td>
         <td>34</td>
         <td>8471320</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>test4</td>
         <td>24</td>
         <td>589</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>test3</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<table id="group2new">
   <thead style="background-color: #00f; color: #fff">
      <tr>
         <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Header4</th>
         <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Header5</th>
         <th data-style="Header" style="background-color: #66cdf2; color: #000">Header6</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>test4</td>
         <td>34</td>
         <td>8471320</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>test5</td>
         <td>24</td>
         <td>589</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>test6</td>
         <td>61</td>
         <td>2</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```